# Is there any battery monitoring program under CLI

Tags: linux, centos, centos6

I wonder if there is a battery monitoring program that can run under console and can warn the user about battery capacity in CentOS.
Sudden shutdown is making me really annoying.

Comment: You can use the script described here [How can I get an alert when my battery is about to die in Linux Mint?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60778/how-can-i-get-an-alert-when-my-battery-is-about-to-die-in-linux-mint)

Comment: @Polentino Thakyou.I can manage it now.

Comment: Solved with following solution with just a few tweaks. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60778/how-can-i-get-an-alert-when-my-battery-is-about-to-die-in-linux-mint

Comment: Glad to help you :)